# Or condition is not working with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I have included given code

```
eventCode ='AUTHORISATION' 
success ='true' 
paymentMethod = 'unionpay'
eventCode == 'AUTHORISATION' && success == 'true' && paymentMethod == ('alipay' || 'unionpay') #returns false
```

above condition returns false but it has to return true why my condition is not working. Please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby has a far more elegant way to check if a value is in a given list:

```
['alipay', 'unionpay'].includes?(paymentMethod)
```

In Rails you can use the ActiveSupport `.in?` method to write the inverse which often makes more semantical sense:

```
paymentMethod.in?(['alipay', 'unionpay'])
```

---

```
eventCode == 'AUTHORISATION' && success == 'true' && paymentMethod.in?(['alipay', 'unionpay'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the below way.

```
eventCode == 'AUTHORISATION' && success == 'true' && (paymentMethod == 'alipay' || paymentMethod== 'unionpay')
```

Because paymentMethod== ('alipay' || 'unionpay') check paymentMethod to only alipay no to the second string.

Answer (score 1):

`'alipay' || 'unionpay'` always evaluates to `'alipay'`, so you effectively wrote `paymentMethod == 'alipay'`. You have to write `(paymentMethod == 'alipay' || paymentMethod == 'unionpay')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
eventCode == 'AUTHORISATION' && success == 'true' && %w{alipay unionpay}.include?(paymentMethod)
```